# Splitting Data in a Column

Tags: sql, t-sql, split

I get some data that comes in to the table.

This table is currently only displaying after I merged all the tables. So you currently see:

```
Table 1 
union
Table 2
union 
Table 3
```

The issue I have is now i have one column in there where it contains data like this:

```
AA2B133
```

I want to split this column, so in the current column it tries to keep the first 3 charachters and the other 4 charachters it goes into another column.

What is the best way or simplest way of doing this.

Thank you

Comment: what's the relation of AA2B133 with the tables in the union? is it in one of them? or is it the result? could you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: Hi yes this is result. Its a example of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RIGHT()`  and `LEFT()` functions to split the data into multiple columns.

For example:

```
SELECT LEFT(data,3), RIGHT(data,4) 
FROM (SELECT 'AA2B133' AS data) A
```

Will return two columns with the breakout you requested.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java to get the 3 first caracters using this

```
String substring (String s, int start, int len)
```

so if you want to get the three first charachters for example you can do like this

```
String substring ("AA2B133",0,2)
```

Comment: So the asker should write a script in Java that connects to his DB to split a string?